# Validation on update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

Good Day,

I'm really new to laravel and having fun using it until I encounter one problem that really gives me pain in programming, It's  the validation redirect during update method. It gives me an error

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

The program is about denying a purchase request and I want the denial to write a note abt the reason of it's denial, that field should not be empty, I can validate it but my problem is the error during redirection.

here is the form for the deny.blade.php

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['prInitialApprovalController@update',$post->id],',method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'pull-right'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('denyNote','Deny Note(Please fill this up for it is required)')}}
    {{Form::textarea('denyNote','', [ 'id'=>'article-ckeditor','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Please fill deny note for it is required'])}}
    </div>    
    {{Form::hidden('denied','11', ['class'=>'form-control'])}}
    {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
    {{Form::submit('Deny', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    <a href="/pr_approval" class="btn btn-dark">Return</a>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

and here is the update method on the controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //update category
    $post = prModel::find($id);

    if($request->input('denied') == '11'){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

    'denyNote' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->action(
            'prInitialApprovalController@deny', $id
        )->withErrors($validator);
     }else{
        $post->pr_status = '11';
        $post->deny_reason = $request->input('denyNote');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/pr_approval')->with('success', 'Purchase Request Denied');
    }
    }
}
```

Here is my web route

```
Route::put('pr_approval/{id}/deny', 'prInitialApprovalController@deny');
Route:: Resource('/pr_approval', 'prInitialApprovalController');
Auth::routes();
```

here is the route list

[image: Route Image]

Please help I'm really stuck on this for like days. I'm using laravel 5.6

Thank you

Comment: try this and let me know {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'col-md-12')) }}
.... wathever code here
{{ Form::close() }} you have to change your method from post to put

Comment: try using route or url instead action ?

Comment: Tried it, still it has the same error

Comment: @motifaithed run this command and post the output in your question. php artisan route:list

Comment: already uploaded the route list image

Comment: execute  `php artisan route:list` and then upload that list

Comment: When I'm redirecting to another page with no parameters involved, say for example a create page, all is well, but when I'm redirecting to a previous page which is an item with id, that's when I get the error

Comment: try this and let me know `return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);` or `return back()->withInput();`

Answer (score 0):

Try use Form with Model binding:

```
{{ Form::model($post, ['route' => ['pr_approval.update', $post->id]]) }}
 // Your Html
{{Form::close}}
```

Also, remove this line.

```
{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using any of these.

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['prInitialApprovalController@update',$post->id],',method'=>'PUT', 'class'=>'pull-right'])!!}
```

**OR**

Add this field in your form :

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

**OR**

You can also do this way :

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['prInitialApprovalController@update',$post->id],',method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'pull-right'])!!}
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Remove this line :

```
{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Problem with your csrf token.

When any form submit you have need the **@csrf** token. laravel 5.6
have some requirment for dending data  with form.

```
         @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <div class="alert alert-danger " style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>Error!</strong>     {{ $error }}
         </div>

         @endforeach //for error

{!!Form::open(['action'=>['prInitialApprovalController@update',$post->id],',method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'pull-right'])!!}
    @csrf
                   <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('denyNote','Deny Note(Please fill this up for it is required)')}}
                            {{Form::textarea('denyNote','', [ 'id'=>'article-ckeditor','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Please fill deny note for it is required'])}}
                        </div>    
                    {{Form::hidden('denied','11', ['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                    {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
                    {{Form::submit('Deny', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
                    <input type="submit value="Return" href="/pr_approval" class="btn btn-dark">
                    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

After @csrf token some cases we have also need your token value/

```
<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value="af22b8f3a43fe074cfa5daf43f6250eba767f1bc" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN" /></div>
```

Also Use

```
 <form action="{{ URL::to('/Registration_store') }} method="POST" >
```

and 
  web.php routes is

```
Route::post('/Registration_store','controller_name@function_name');
```

You not need this code laravel automatically throw the error preview page.

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->action(
            'prInitialApprovalController@deny', $id
        )->withErrors($validator);
     }
```